# sql insert query clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table A which contains fields

```
 ChangeID    DistributionID     OutletBrandID
```

and Table B contains

```
 ID       DistributionID      OutletBrandID
```

I need to insert data in table A from table B only if the distributionID and OutletBrandID combination doesn't exist already. Therefore I can't simply use the IN clause as it needs to be a combination.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/requirements lists. We are not here to do your job for you.

Comment: Once you do formulate a question, edit this and include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that ChangeID and ID should match between the tables:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ChangeID, DistributionID, OutletBrandID)
SELECT b.ID, b.DistributionID, b.OutletBrandID FROM TableB b
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA a ON a.DistributionID=b.DistributionID
AND a.OutletBrandID = b.OutletBrandID
WHERE
a.OutletBrandID IS NULL
AND
a.DistributionID IS NULL
```